# Stylelint, have an empty line before non-nested rules and no empty line before nested rules?

Tags: stylelint

Is there any way at all to accomplish this now?

I see rule-nested-empty-line-before has been removed for some reason, so is this config no longer possible?

I want this to throw errors...

```
@media (max-width: 300px) {

    .foo {
        display: block;
    }
}
@media (max-width: 600px) {
    .bar {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

There should be a space before @media since it's not nested, and no space before .foo since it's nested.

Answer (score 6):

The `rule-nested-empty-line-before` and `rule-non-nested-empty-line-before` rules were combined together to form the new [`rule-empty-line-before`](https://github.com/stylelint/stylelint/blob/master/lib/rules/rule-empty-line-before/README.md) rule in version [`8.0.0`](https://github.com/stylelint/stylelint/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#800). You can use this rule to control the empty lines before the `.foo {}` and `.bar {}` rules.

`@media` is an at-rule, so you should use the [`at-rule-empty-line-before`](https://github.com/stylelint/stylelint/blob/master/lib/rules/at-rule-empty-line-before/README.md) rule to control the empty lines before it.

You can learn about how rules are named and how they work together [in this section of the User Guide](https://github.com/stylelint/stylelint/blob/master/docs/user-guide/about-rules.md).

> There should be a space before @media since it's not nested, and no space before .foo since it's nested.

With the above in mind, the configuration for that should be:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "at-rule-empty-line-before": ["always"],
    "rule-empty-line-before": ["always", {
      except: ["first-nested"]
    }]
  }
}
```

Alternatively, you can use [`stylelint-standard-config`](https://github.com/stylelint/stylelint-config-standard), which has sensible defaults for stylistic rules.